# Firefox session storage is empty

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, firefox

Codeigniter:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $userinfo);
if(isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in'])){
    echo 1;
}
```

When I am calling this function by using ajax method it displaying me 1. it means session is set. but after redirection I check storage there is no session How can I resolve this error please help me it working well in Chrome.

**Edit-1:** I checked by using firebug session is set but after redirection there is no session. I am redirecting to same page.

Comment: If it's a browser specific bug, you'll need to show the HTML and Javascript involved. The issue is definitely not server side in any direct way.

Answer (score 2):

You must use parenthesis, not those brackets

```
$this->session->userdata('item');
```